# Search submit button in all forms with textareas with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a Firefox-plugin which searches a webpage for all textareas and places a warning before the submit button.

my code looks like this

```
var submitWarning = content.document.createElement("div");
submitWarning.innerHTML = "Fancy Message";
$('textarea', window.content.document).each(function() {
    var form = $(this, window.content.document).parents('form:first');
    $(form, window.content.document).children('input[type=submit]').each(function() {
         form.insertBefore(submitWarning, this);
    });
});
```

if i search all submits with `$('input[type=submit]'.each` it works fine but since i added the thing with the textarea and the `form:first` i got problems (nothing happens)

p.s. i use the window.content.document thingy because its a ff-plugin and it won't work nothing without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it a bit, like this:

```
var submitWarning = content.document.createElement("div");
submitWarning.innerHTML = "Fancy Message";
$('textarea', window.content.document)
   .closest('form')
   .find('input[type=submit]')
   .before(submitWarning);
```

The argument syntax is [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), when finding the form, first there's [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) which makes this easier, also when you have an element, you can just use `$(this)` inside it's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), no need to search for it again.  Also, you can use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before) to make it easier :)

Answer (score 1):

The [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector is the best choice for me. Get rid of your extensive code and use this instead.

```
var buttons = $("form:has(textarea) input[type=submit]", window.content.document);
$("<div>").html("Fancy Message").insertBefore(buttons);
```

Comment: Elegant, but expensive :)  Also I'm not sure the document fragment creation style works inside of a FF plugin, If you need `window.content.document`, I would think `document.createDocumentFragment()` would need to be aliased as well, it isn't inside jQuery: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L415

Comment: Why expensive? If you're about to answer 'because of the *:has* selector, do you actually *know* how it works? :)

Comment: Yes I know how it works, keep in mind you're doing a tree search twice, instead of a `getElementsByTagName`, parent climb then tree search, which is faster.  `:has(selector)` is just a wrapper for `!!$(selector, context).length`

Answer (score 0):

Try `var form = $(this, window.content.document).closest('form');`. Not sure if that's the ticket, but it's the first thing off my head.